# What does it mean to sling one’s belt low?

Tags: difference

Context: “Olson slung his belt low on his hips like a gunslinger,”

Does sling one’s belt low mean wear one’s belt low? Is there any difference between the two phrases? If so, an actual picture by picture comparison highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this expression used in particular context?  Can you tell us the context please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means to wear a belt low on the body, typically at the hips instead of the waist (or somewhere between the waist and hips).

That particular phrasing is unusual--you might encounter this more frequently described as a "low-slung belt," or in the passive voice.

> I.e., "She wore a low-slung belt" or "the leather belt was slung low around her hips" rather than "She slung a belt low around her hips."

An image search of low-slung belt will give you an idea of what it looks like. Low-slung belts were a fashion trend in the US in the early 2000s.

Comment: In that case, can you say a low hung/(or hanging) belt instead?

Comment: @Ray No, you couldn't say that.

Answer (score 1):

"Gunslingers" in the American West wore the belt on which their gun was carried (in a holster) low on their hips to make withdrawing the gun for use quicker.

In this picture you can see the man has two belts: one to help keep his trousers up, around his waist, and a gun belt 'slung' over his hips.

[image]